# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in NotesController#showの意味

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in NotesController#showと表示されました。 
Couldn't find Note with 'id'=showとさらに表示されました。 
notes_controller.rbのprivateメソット以下のset_noteメソットがおかしいようで 
def set_note 
      @note = Note.find(params[:id])←ここの部分がおかしい 
    end 
と表示されました。 
idがshowメソットに記されていないという認識で間違いないですよね？ 
SequelProを見ても、notesテーブルにきちんと投稿したカラムにidが書かれています。 
何かコマンドを打ち忘れ、データが反映されていないのでしょうか？ 
回答お願いします。
routes.rbは 
Rails.application.routes.draw do

devise_for :users 
  resources :users, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update] 
  resources :notes, only: [:show, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]

get'/top' => 'home#top'

get'/connection' => 'home#connection' 
  get'/notes/new' => 'notes#new' 
  post'/notes' =>'notes#create' 
  get'/notes' =>'notes#index' 
  get'/show' =>"notes#show" 
  get'/edit' =>'notes#edit' 
  patch'/notes/:id' =>"notes#update",as:'update_note' 
  delete'/notes/:id' =>"notes#destroy",as:'destroy_note'

post '/like/:note_id' => 'likes#like', as: 'like' 
  delete '/unlike/:note_id' => 'likes#unlike', as: 'unlike'

root 'home#top' 
  get'/about' => 'home#about' 
end 
のようになっています。 
idはshowである、のように記述していないのでは？と思って困っています。 
お願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*idがshowメソットに記されていないという認識で間違いないですよね？

idはshowである、のように記述していないのでは？*

間違いです。

`Couldn't find Note with 'id'=show`は「Noteクラスで表されるデータの中には'id'フィールドの値が"show"であるものは見つかりませんでした」と言っています。「idはshowである」のような記述が必要だと言っているのではありません。

Answer (score 0):

`params[:id]`が"show"になっているようです。
これは`http://server/notes/show`か`http://server/notes/show/1`のようなURLでnoteを表示(show)しようとしている、ということだと思います。実際は`http://server/notes/1`とか、`/notes/[id]`の形式で表示(show)します。

Comment: なるほど！質問にコードを追加したのですが、idはshowである、のように記述していないのでは？と思って困っています。 教えてください、お願いします。

Comment: showにidが渡されていないように見えます。`get'/show' =>"notes#show" `を`get'/show/:id' => 'notes#show'`に直してみてください。